# Vim / Neovim Why use autocommands when you have lua functions?

Tags: vim, lua, neovim

I have some experience with vim but most of my time has been spent in neovim playing around with lua (although I'm still barely not a beginner). I missed out on the vimscript autocommand magic that I see alot of people pulling off and I'm wondering why not just write a lua function like...

```lua
function OpenTerm()
  vim.cmd("bel split")
  vim.cmd("terminal")
  vim.cmd("setlocal nonumber norelativenumber")
end
```

instead of writing a an autocmd ?

Comment: I'm also relatively new to NeoVim (though I have been using the motions with vscode+VsCodeVim for about 6 years and browsing via Vimperator and clones for about the same time). Just wanted to comment to say thanks for asking a question, even if people are going to respond in a less than friendly manner. I'm trying to understand autocommands, and this Q & A has helped a bit on it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are conflating two *totally* unrelated things.

Your snippet (assuming it works, I don't use Neovim  so I won't test it):

```
function OpenTerm()
  vim.cmd("bel split")
  vim.cmd("terminal")
  vim.cmd("setlocal nonumber norelativenumber")
end
```

is a Lua function that is exactly equivalent to this Vimscript function:

```
function! OpenTerm()
  bel split
  terminal
  setlocal nonumber norelativenumber
endfunction
```

and both functions have literally nothing to do with autocommands. They are completely passive and defining them only did some low-level memory-related things. For them to do anything, *you have to call them*.

Autocommands are a very different thing that allows you to tell Vim to perform some action when an event occurs, like this one:

```
autocmd VimEnter * call OpenTerm()
```

which, essentially, tells Vim this:

> When you are done starting up, call the `OpenTerm()` function.

Unlike functions, which do nothing until they are called, autocommands have a real effect on your editor's state as soon as they are defined.

You can add an autocommand from a function, you can call a function from an autocommand, but you can't expect one to act as the other.

Basically, the question "Do I use an autocommand or a function?" makes no sense at all.